# Materialize - How to know the class options we can set?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am starting with Materialize and I wonder how to know every element we can set a class attribute for example?

```
<div class = " A LOT OF ELEMENTS ">
```

On their website, they just provide a few examples and we do not have the scope of all the possibilities.

Also, I found this [website](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#) but they only provide information about what is possible without detailing how to do it... And it is frustrating!

For example, I have two cards and would like to reduce the space between them, I cannot find the information anywhere.

Thank you,

Olivia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see absolutely all the options you must see the definition of the classes in the file materialize.css. If you want to reduce the space between some element you must use the box model (CSS).